# TypeScript Generics: defining type intersection with a union

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm building a TypeScript library that leverages some interfaces from another library. I'm trying to define a type from the intersection of a generic type and an interface I don't control, combined with a union between `void`, which has special meaning in the dependency library.

I've tried to create a minimal representation of the issue I'm facing.

```js
export type AllProps<Props> = (Props & IDependecyProps) | void;

interface MyProps {
  disableCache: boolean;
}

function doTheThing(props: AllProps<MyProps>) {
  // Property 'disableCache' does not exist on type 'AllProps'.
  //  Property 'disableCache' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339)
  console.log(props.disableCache);
}
```

My goal is that the `AllProps` should allow you to specify either `disableCache`, and any properties in `IDependecyProps`, OR the type results in `void`. The library I depend on has a special meaning for `void` type, which makes it useful.

EDIT: I made the code sample too simple, forgot to add the generic type.

Comment: How can there be type results in void?

Comment: The question is not really clear, but simple `if` will refine the type and exclude the `void`. [Try](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgIhSA7AJhAxiACgJwPZgDOUAvFAN5QBmeeAXFEgK4C2ARhDlAL4CwAUANCQoAQQA243AWJkAFAFls+IlABksBMjSZpRAJRQAPlABueAJYoA3AIEWkwTlQCG6aEr3FyAqFBQWhC5s4hAAwm4AFhAMbLShLki2-HyC-FRMSOjAFnhI-ngAKtHFDgDmcmAqhAwSUtWGPvx+FlRQlQ1Q6HmEeKEAdOJ4FVUy-QFBIeFREPrJ3EA)

Comment: @AlekseyL., that was exactly all that was needed. Simple `if(props)` statement allowed TypeScript to exclude the `void` and assume my type intersection. It works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple `if` will refine the type and exclude the `void`:

```
function doTheThing(props: AllProps) {
  if (props) {
    console.log(props.disableCache); // props is narrowed to MyProps & IDependecyProps
  }
}
```

Control flow analysis narrows type of `props` inside `if` to `MyProps & IDependecyProps`.

Also `if` is needed anyway to prevent error at runtime (`props` parameter can be `undefined` according to its type definition).

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgIhSA7AJhAxiACgJwPZgDOUAvFAN5QBmeeAXFEgK4C2ARhDlAL4CwAUANCQoAQQA243AWJkAFAFls%20IlABksBMjSZpRAJRQAPlABueAJYoA3AIEWkwTlQCG6aEr3FyAqFBQWhC5s4hAAwm4AFhAMbLShLki2-HyC-FRMSOjAFnhI-ngAKtHFDgDmcmAqhAwSUtWGPvx%20FlRQlQ0Uvn5Q6HmEeKEAdOJ4FVUyQwFBIeFREPrWAPRLUBOqgYwuOPgA7hAoUMB4UJ7V6pqIEKgYyjLdqdxAA)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a type assertion on your props and check for the existence of the property, since your example is `boolean` we need to check if it is not `undefined`

[Read More Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=13&ssc=69&pln=12&pc=1#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQEkAiUAOUwAmUSAngAowD2OAzqgN7CrOo2UC2UEAFuAOYAuVGACu7AEaxgAX2BQAHjkowIqCCTyoAggBsdFanQC8qABQBZclVqoAZBmx5CxK4YCUqAD6oAbpRAEANzAoJCwiCiolgY2jMwEIDQI4jpQAMLI3FBC4pSUqQhgwbLAcCJgSBAglGCoBJQAKllN-KY41jRCuvodHoxMqCBwZmoaUJRwpm0dqAh00b0AdAlJKemZUG4AhEZGAOTlRHDgUAR7qG4DSDVsqYs6lHxT7Yaz8660bsuJyakZSFk3MVgPUmlAWmAnvQ6j81v8skJEDoaFAADSsDhcXiQgQARmkbiAA)

```
interface IDependecyProps {
    something: number
}
export type AllProps = (MyProps & IDependecyProps) | void;

interface MyProps {
  disableCache: boolean;
}

function doTheThing(props: AllProps) {

  if ( typeof((props as MyProps).disableCache)!=='undefined' )
  console.log((props as MyProps).disableCache);
}
doTheThing({ disableCache: false, something:1})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=48#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQEkAiUAOUwAmUSAngAowD2OAzqgN7CrOo2UC2UEAFuAOYAuVGACu7AEaxgAX2BQAHjkowIqCCTyoAggBsdFanQC8qABQBZclVqoAZBmx5CxK4YCUqAD6oAbpRAEANzAoJCwiCiolgY2jMwEIDQI4jpQAMLI3FBC4pSUqQhgwbLAcCJgSBAglGCoBJQAKllN-KY41jRCuvodHnGoAPQDqDGw6qgA5AlJKemZUBN1lFB0YJSqComqNWoaaBPdMTQTAHRMg8Mj1mMkk9PJqRlIWYv1K8LrqJs027XqmhM-AFThAaKYAEwAZkhAE43OcQHAzLs8JQ4KY2h1UAg6NFeid7rMnlk3ABCIxGCblIhwcBQAiLeHMJA1NipE46Sh8DHtQzY3GuWhuAmJB5zZ5QNzFYD1JpQFpgbn0OqionzISIHQ0KAAGlYHC4vEVAgAjNI3EA)

Comment: Sorry, it seems I oversimplified the code sample. This would work if I knew exactly what types to expect at all times, but there's actually a generic in there. I wonder, could I somehow infer what the generic type `Props` is, then use type assertion as you suggest?